# Remove the kendo dropdown arrow icon from menu item title that is also an icon

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, icons

I'm using Kendo to render li's as demoed in their [menu widget](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/index). Because one of the menu items itself happens to be an action icon, I'm having a hard time removing the drop down icon arrow that appears next to it. Kendo's example only uses text headers, not icons, so I'm unsure of how to remove the dropdown icon from this action button menu item.

Typically the arrow is removed via css's `display: none setting` but applying this to the class name with the icon just hides the icon as well and we are using Less.js to render CSS stylings

I have done multiple variations of  `li .k-icon { display: none; }`
with no success. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the demo below.

I've placed a class named `hide-arrow` on two `li` elements in the menu, Decor and Stores.

I've also added the following styling:

```
.hide-arrow>.k-menu-link>.k-menu-expand-arrow>.k-menu-expand-arrow-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

**Note:** This approach works for some versions of the kendo-ui library but might break in other versions if they have a different internal structure. If you decide to update the library, you'll have to update the selector to suit the new element hierarchy if it indeed changes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/menu/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/styles/kendo.default-main.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.1.119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="megaStore">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    Products
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Furniture
                            <ul>
                                <li>Tables & Chairs</li>
                                <li>Sofas</li>
                                <li>Occasional Furniture</li>
                                <li>Children's Furniture</li>
                                <li>Beds</li>
                            </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li class="hide-arrow">
                            Decor
                            <ul>
                                <li>Bed Linen</li>
                                <li>Throws</li>
                                <li>Curtains & Blinds</li>
                                <li>Rugs</li>
                                <li>Carpets</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Storage
                            <ul>
                                <li>Wall Shelving</li>
                                <li>Kids Storage</li>
                                <li>Baskets</li>
                                <li>Multimedia Storage</li>
                                <li>Floor Shelving</li>
                                <li>Toilet Roll Holders</li>
                                <li>Storage Jars</li>
                                <li>Drawers</li>
                                <li>Boxes</li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Lights
                            <ul>
                                <li>Ceiling</li>
                                <li>Table</li>
                                <li>Floor</li>
                                <li>Shades</li>
                                <li>Wall Lights</li>
                                <li>Spotlights</li>
                                <li>Push Light</li>
                                <li>String Lights</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="hide-arrow">
                    Stores
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div id="template" style="padding: 10px;">
                                <h2>Around the Globe</h2>
                                <ol>
                                    <li>United States</li>
                                    <li>Europe</li>
                                    <li>Canada</li>
                                    <li>Australia</li>
                                </ol>
                                <img src="../content/web/menu/map.png" alt="Stores Around the Globe" />
                                <button class="k-button k-button-solid-base k-button-solid k-button-rectangle k-button-md k-rounded-md">See full list</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Blog
                </li>
                <li>
                    Company
                </li>
                <li>
                    Events
                </li>
                <li disabled="disabled">
                    News
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <style>
            #megaStore {
                max-width: 600px;
                margin: 30px auto;
                padding-top: 120px;
                background: url('../content/web/menu/header.jpg') no-repeat center 0;
            }
            #menu h2 {
                font-size: 1em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
            #template img {
                margin: 5px 20px 0 0;
                float: left;
            }
            #template {
                width: 380px;
            }
            #template ol {
                float: left;
                margin: 0 0 0 30px;
                padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            }
            #template:after {
                content: ".";
                display: block;
                height: 0;
                clear: both;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            #template .k-button {
                float: left;
                clear: left;
                margin: 5px 0 5px 12px;
            }
          
            .hide-arrow>.k-menu-link>.k-menu-expand-arrow>.k-menu-expand-arrow-icon {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#menu").kendoMenu();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shai I'm actually glad you shared this, it proved my hypothesis that this can be done with text only. I replaced the "Decor" item with a kendo icon and it did not render the icon at all but the functionality was still there. I dont think Kendo supports this functionality and I will have to find another way to achieve this. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Did you use the exact selector I wrote above?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: Shai you are right, after using a different web font icon, I was able to reproduce the behavior I was looking for in the kendo dojo. Unfortunately for my project some of our classes are nested sooo deeply that I am still trying to configure the right selector however this IS the solution, thank you for your help!

Comment: You are right this is possible! I'm not sure the overarching issue but some of Kendo's web font icons dont seem to play well when being used as an menu item, however your encouragement made me go deeper and I *was* able to solve the problem in my project as well! I should have mentioned we are using Less.js so the formatting for this as slightly different but I was able to figure it out. Im new to Kendo so this was really helpful, thank you again! https://dojo.telerik.com/avIfoxIz